# How To Load All Product Details Using Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

Hello i created custom product attribute with Yes/No Value.
for Product Information Page.
If attribute Value Is Yes Then Display Products Details.
But Whenever I Call, **getAttributeText** displayes **null**.
I dont'd know what is the error.

i created one **phtml file call special_product**.
in this file i call attribute.
but its not work.

pls help me.

how to load product details if attribute value is "Yes"?

Comment: please share the phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that ?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check `frontend property` value like `Used in Product Listing` set to `yes` also set `Visible on Product view page on Frontend` to `yes`. where you created the attribute.

If above value is `yes` then you can call attribute value like this:-

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('custom attribute'); ?>
```

and as per your requirement I think you have to set `if` condition into your product page. like below:-

```
    if($_product->getAttributeText('custom attribute')=='yes'){

        your product details code.....
    }
```